# Console.log on Eclipse with cordova throws error

Tags: eclipse, console, cordova

I have just started using Cordova (2.3.0) and Eclipse for mobile development and when I try in the javascript code to log a console message, i get the following error in the Eclipse log:

Property 'console' of object [object DOMwindow] is not a function.

I am using the standard console.log('xxxx') call but it's not working.

---

## Solved

**This was my bad. I was trying to invoque the console function prior to deviceReady. Got it to work.**

Comment: Which device are you testing in?

Comment: I am using the emulator.